# I'm trying to toggle the top margin of a div on click.

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, toggle

I'm trying to shift a div from it's initial position with a top margin of 22em to 0 when clicked. Every other click should revert it to 22em.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container3" class="isDown">
<div class="test" id="name3">

</div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{margin-top: 22em;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#container3").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
        $("#name3").animate({marginTop:"0em"});          
        $(this).removeClass("isDown");
    } else {
        $("#name3").animate({marginTop:"22em"});   
        $(this).addClass("isDown");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Sorry if it's a mess. I have no idea what I'm doing!

Comment: Your code works as you described. Have you tried it? http://jsfiddle.net/UHD7M/1/

Comment: make sure the script is added in a dom ready handler

Answer (score 0):

Try toggleClass with css class like

**style**

```
.test{margin-top: 22em;}
```

**Script**

```
$("#container3").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#name3").toggleClass('test');          
    $(this).toggleClass("isDown");   
    return false;
});
```